# Excel - Match item http string and display result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have column H that contains long GET requests on sheet 1 such as:

```
H
GET /profiles/text/23493495_3492/g93id93kd
GET /edit/result/393493/te3903k4d
```

I would like to have a second sheet with the following type of list in columns A and B:

```
A                  B
23493495           identifier1
3903k4             realid2
g93id              realid3
```

Ultimately, I would like a function that will search sheet 1 column H for any of the values in sheet 2 column A.  Most of the time there is no separator so I need it to search for strings within the GET string.  Once a value in sheet 2 column A is matched with a value in sheet 1 column H, I would like the function to take the corresponding text in sheet 2 column B and print it in sheet 1 column I.  There may be multiple matches in a cell, so that would need to be taken into account.  So if using the example above:

In H1, there would be a match of 23493495 and g93id within the string.  I would like sheet 1 column I to display:

```
I
identifier1, realid3
```

I initially started with the below code where I had to specify the list but it doesn't use a second sheet or print the corresponding text of the match.  So I would rather have something that meets my needs above, but below is an example of what I have tried so far:

```
=ListSearchB(J2, "23493495 g93id")
```

With this module I found that I modified a little:

```
    Function ListSearchB(text As String, wordlist As String, Optional caseSensitive As Boolean = False)
    Dim strMatches As String
    Dim res As Variant
    Dim arrWords() As String
    arrWords = Split(wordlist)
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    For Each word In arrWords
        If caseSensitive = False Then
            res = InStr(LCase(text), LCase(word))
        Else
            res = InStr(text, word)
        End If
        If res > 0 Then
            strMatches = strMatches & word
        End If
    Next word
    If Len(strMatches) <> 0 Then
        strMatches = Right(strMatches, Len(strMatches))
    End If
    ListSearchB = strMatches
End Function
```

That gives me:

23493495g93id in column I, and I wasn't sure how to separate the two with a comma.

In general though, I would prefer, to use some way to pull the list from sheet 2 and display the value in column I as specified initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try - just adjust the sheet names where commented before running

```
Sub your_sub()
    Dim sGet As Worksheet
    Dim sIDs As Worksheet
    Dim rget As Range
    Dim rIds As Range

    'ADJUST SHEET NAME
    With Worksheets("GET")
        Set rget = Range(.Range("H1"), .Range("h" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    'ADJUST SHEET NAME
    With Worksheets("IDs")
        Set rIds = Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    mys = vbNullString
    i = 1

    For Each cget In rget

        For Each cIds In rIds
            If InStr(cget.Value, cIds) <> 0 Then
                mys = mys & ", " & cIds.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next cIds

        If mys <> vbNullString Then
            mys = Right(mys, Len(mys) - 2)
            'ADJUST SHEET NAME
            Worksheets("GET").Range("I" & i).Value = mys
        End If

        i = i + 1
        mys = vbNullString

    Next cget

End Sub
```

Comment: That works great, thanks!  Btw, I added: Option Compare Text to the top line to allow for case insensitivity.